# How to display the rows on pyqt4's QTableView fetched from the mysql database table

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt4, mysql-python, pyside

How to display the rows on pyqt4's QTableView fetched from the MySQL database table?

Must connect to MySQL via MySQLdb.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass a [QStandardItemModel](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QStandardItemModel.html?highlight=qstandarditemmodel#) and fetch data from any database you like. Then you may use [QTableView.setModel](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractItemView.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAbstractItemView.setModel) function to view data using QTableView.